# Separate column by matching strings

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyr, stringr

I have a dataframe looking like more or less like this:

```
name_position
RAHEEM STERLINGForward
MARCUS RASHFORDForward
JORDAN HENDERSONMidfielder
JORDAN PICKFORDGoalkeeper
KYLE WALKERDefender
```

My purpose is to create two columns of this previous one, so I've created a vector containing all the available positions

`positions <- c("Goalkeeper", "Defender", "Midfielder", "Forward")`

Then I've been trying with functions such as `separate()`, `extract()` or even `str_match`, but I'm not being able to get the output I desire to reach, which would look this way:

```
name                   position
RAHEEM STERLING        Forward
MARCUS RASHFORD        Forward
JORDAN HENDERSON       Midfielder
JORDAN PICKFORD        Goalkeeper
KYLE WALKER            Defender
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `separate` with a regex lookaround

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  separate(name_position, into = c("name", "position"), 
           sep="(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])")
#             name   position
#1  RAHEEM STERLING    Forward
#2  MARCUS RASHFORD    Forward
#3 JORDAN HENDERSON Midfielder
#4  JORDAN PICKFORD Goalkeeper
#5      KYLE WALKER   Defender
```

---

If we have a custom vector, then one option is to create a `pat`tern vector by creating a single string

```
library(stringr)
pat <- str_c(positions, collapse="|")
df1 %>% 
   transmute(name = str_remove(name_position, pat),
            position = str_extract(name_position, pat))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(name_position = c("RAHEEM STERLINGForward", "MARCUS RASHFORDForward", 
"JORDAN HENDERSONMidfielder", "JORDAN PICKFORDGoalkeeper", 
"KYLE WALKERDefender"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `str_extract`from `stringr`:

```
df1$position <- str_extract(df1$name_position, "(?<=[A-Z])[A-Z][a-z]+")
```

Result:

```
df1
               name_position   position
1     RAHEEM STERLINGForward    Forward
2     MARCUS RASHFORDForward    Forward
3 JORDAN HENDERSONMidfielder Midfielder
4  JORDAN PICKFORDGoalkeeper Goalkeeper
5        KYLE WALKERDefender   Defender
```

This solution uses positive lookbehind:

`(?<=[A-Z])`  if you see an upper-case letter on left ...

`[A-Z][a-z]+` ... match the subsequent upper-case letter plus the one or more lower-case letters following it